# License Plate recognition using AForge.Net

Tags: aforge

i am currently doing a project for "Automatic Number Plate Detection and
Recognition" and i am using AForge.Net ;i have used a simple algo;
 though it is not very efficient but it will fulfills my requirements.
i have calculated height,width and height to width(height/width) ratio of more than 
40 car's numberplate; i searched for the rectangles in the image which lie in the range
of height, width and height to width ratio; now with this i am able to detect the 
number plate for most of the images but the problem is that along with 
the number plate; i am getting some other rectangles; which also lies
in the range of height/width ratio; now i want to differentiate between 
the rectangle containing the number plate and the rectangles without the
number plate; [actually i am cropping the rectangles and storing them in Bitmaps]
now i have 2 solutions to solve this but i don't know how to implement them.

i. i can make an assumption that the background of number plate is white(it is
not true always but it will work for most of the cases (i am ready for the 
trafeoffs)); my question is that is there any built-in method in Aforge.Net that
can search the white background from a picture; or how can i find that the 
given picture has white background?? [if a picture has a white background then 
it is a number plate else not]

ii. another option is to detect the characters from the image; any image
containing characters [we can assume that there should be atleast 4 character;
so we should search in an image that if it has 4 or more than 4 characters then it is 
a number plate else not] ; so is there any method available in AForge which can be helpful in this case i.e which can search for characters;
if not then how can i search the characters through an image...?

Is there any other options; other than the two above ??

If for above 2 implementations; there is a solution in emguCV , even then do let me know; i can do a portion of work with emguCV also.

PLz  reply me early as this is my college project ; and now only a little time
is left...

regards
usama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the rhonmbus into a rectangle, divide the rectangle into 4x8. Compute median luminence in each rectangle and curve fit to known data set.

Run a guassian over the image before computing the normalized luminance to account for stickers and scratches and camera anomalies. Desaturate and quantize into 4 levels or so, the lightest color in the picture will be 0 the darkest is 100.